# copy of a string pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have a function that has input and pointer to an array of char in C. in that function I am manipulating the main string, however I want to make a backup copy in another variable before I use it. I want to put it in char backup[2000], so if the pointer changes the backup won't change. 
How can I do that?

Comment: Look up a function called strncpy.

Comment: @GWW `strncpy` is an abomination. The correct approach here is to use strlen on the string to be sure it fits into the buffer, then use either strcpy(buffer, string) or memcpy(buffer, string, len+1) (the latter is  faster on many architectures).

Comment: @Jim Balter: WHat happens if the string is not null terminated?

Comment: @GWW Then it's not a string. If it's just an array of bytes, then the OP must know its length, and can just use memcpy(buffer, mem, len) (after checking that len <= sizeof(buffer)).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
void function (const char *string)
{
   char *stringcopy = malloc (1 + strlen (string));
   if (stringcopy)
       strcpy (stringcopy, string);
   else  fprintf (stderr, "malloc failure!"):
   ...
   do whatever needs to be done with `stringcopy`
}
```

Comment: POSIX provides strdup, which does the malloc and strcpy for you.

Answer (score 9):

To duplicate strings in C there is a library function called [`strdup`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) made for that:

The memory allocated by `strdup` must be freed after usage using `free`.

`strdup` provides the memory allocation and string copy operation in one step. Using an char array can become problematic if at some point in time the string to copy happens to be larger than the array's size.

Comment: The OP wants to copy it to an array

Comment: Ok, but maybe it is a better alternative he didn't think of if he's already asking for something as basic as copying a string. The accepted answer does something similar.

Comment: @Andy The OP isn't even out of C diapers and has no idea what the best solution is. This is a fundamental rule that you should learn: requests for solutions often consist of premature design, rather than requirements. Always be sure that the client provides the latter, not the former.

Comment: @Andy P.S. The OP accepted an answer that uses malloc and strcpy, equivalent to strdup. That should tell you something.

Answer (score 2):

Your friends are the following functions

- malloc
- memset
- calloc
- memcpy
- strcpy
- strdup
- strncpy

But best of all, greatest friend is **man** :)

Answer (score 1):

Use strncpy().

```
void myfunc(char* inputstr)
{
    char backup[2000];
    strncpy(backup, inputstr, 1999);
    backup[1999] = '\0';
}
```

Copying 1999 characters to the 2000 character array leaves the last character for the null terminator.

Comment: Only if you actually set `backup[1999]` to 0 somewhere.

Comment: @Thanatos  If the length of `inputstr` is less than 1999 then `strncpy` will pad the `backup` string with nulls. But good point... have edited to show setting of null terminator for the case where the length >= 1999.

Comment: strncpy is an abomination. Never recommend it, at least not without a host of caviats. That your original code was buggy was predictable, as was the fact that your edited code still slams memory with numerous unneeded NUL stores. Also, you're storing into local memory and then discarding it -- pretty useless. And you have three copies of a constant when you should only have one (google DRY). These are all poor, unprofessional practices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/) to make a copy of your char array (string) before you start modifying.

Answer (score 0):

Use memcpy to create the backup.

```
char backup[2000];
char original[2000];

sprintf(original, "lovely data here");
memcpy(backup, original, 2000);

char* orig_ptr = original;
```

Comment: Fail if `strlen(original) > 1999`, and those three instances of "2000" are bad practice.

Comment: the example is meant to demonstrate the idea...not be production worthy code

Comment: Answers that use bad practices are bad answers.

Answer (score 0):

[strcpy reference.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/)

```
strcpy( backup, source );
```

Note from link.

> To avoid overflows, the size of the array pointed by destination shall be long enough to contain the same C string as source (including the terminating null character), and should not overlap in memory with source.

Comment: So give an answer that actually obeys the caveat.